# google speech recognition api v2 interim results

Tags: node.js, speech-recognition, google-speech-api

I have been working on google speech recognition API v2 using node js npm google-speech-api https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-speech-api
it is working, but i need to get the "interim results".

How can i get the interim results of the audio being processing. I have searched online but not able to find helpful information and make it work.

Below is the code i am working on currently:

```
var speech = require('google-speech-api');
var fs              = require('fs');

var opts = {
  file: 'amy_16.wav',
  key: 'xxxx',
};

speech(opts, function (err, results) {
 console.log(JSON.stringify(results));
 // [{result: [{alternative: [{transcript: '...'}]}]}]
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you aren't using streaming recognition. In order to get partial results you'll need to use `speech.createRecognizeStream` and set the `interimResults` config flag to true. For example:

```
var request = {
    config: {
        encoding: 'LINEAR16',
        sampleRate: 16000
    },
    singleUtterance: false,
    interimResults: true
};

fs.createReadStream('amy_16.wav')
    .on('error', console.error)
    .pipe(speech.createRecognizeStream(request))
    .on('error', console.error)
    .on('data', function(data) {
        //do something with the data
        console.log(data)
});
```

Not sure what you are trying to achieve, but to simplify things you might want to check out [Sonus](https://github.com/evancohen/sonus). It's an always listening speech recognition framework and it supports partial results out of the box. It also does hotword detection. Disclaimer: this is my project